# Is the set of continuous functions a Borel measurable subset of $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $C([0,1])$ be the set of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ and $L^2([0,1])$
the Hilbert space of (equivalence classes) of square-integrable realvalued functions on $[0,1]$.

Then $C([0,1])$ can be identified with a subset of $L^2([0,1])$. I am wondering if $C([0,1])$ is in the Borel sigma-algebra of $L^2([0,1])$.

(It is well-known that $C([0,1])$ is not an element of the product sigma-algebra of the product space $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$, because the latter only sees a countable set of values of a function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check L. Schwartz "Radon measures on arbitrary topological spaces and cylindrical measures," p.101.

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Then every Lusin subspace $A$ (with the induced topology) of $X$ is Borel in $X.$

Image of $C([0,1])$ in $L^2([0,1])$ is a Lusin space as $C([0,1])$ is complete, metric and separable. See definition of [Lusin space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space#Lusin_spaces).

Comment: But $C([0,1])$, with the induced $L^2([0,1])$ topology, is not complete.

Comment: As far as I understand, @dsh is using the fact that "a Hausdorff topological space is a Lusin space if some stronger topology makes it into a Polish space" (as written on the linked Wikipedia page). In this case, the stronger topology would be the uniform topology, which indeed turns C([0,1]) into a  Polish space.

Comment: This, together with the fact "A subspace of a Lusin space is Lusin if and only if it is a Borel set" (also taken form the Wikipedia link, or, alternatively, using the quote from Schwartz's book, which gives the interesting direction for the problem) seems indeed to prove the claim.

Comment: @JaKub I think, one can also use English translation of Bourbaki's "General Topology" ch.IX. Note that English translation uses restricted definitions of Lusin/Souslin spaces (metrizability is required, not only Hausdorffness) which is different from latest French version and from Schwartz.

Answer (score 1):

Both $C[0,1]$ and $L^{p}[0,1]$ are polish. The embedding map $$f: C[0,1] \hookrightarrow L^{p}[0,1]$$ is continuous (therefore borel measurable) and injective. So, $f(C[0,1])$ is Borel subset of $L^{p}[0,1]$.